# React Native - Open Old Version Project (up to 0.48v)

Tags: android, npm, react-native, launching-application

I learning React-Native with Windows 10, Using Git Bash Command Prompt and Android Studio Emulator.

I have Install React Native globally by using `npm install -g react-native-cli`, I always create Project using `react-native init ProjectName` and

**My Project Launching Method** is

go into Project Directory with Git Bash CMD and execute `react-native run-android`.

I notice that most of the Project in Github are older version which consist of `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` (My Project is newer version so it only have `index.js`). I been trying to open some older version Project, but it seem like it just does not launch with the **method** I mentioned above.

I also have tried `react-native start` method from [How to open existing project in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764999/how-to-open-existing-project-in-react-native) but I still not able to launch it.

The **error message** when I trying to launch the project is `Command unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.` This Problem only occur when I trying to launch project from Github, when I open my own Project there is no such problem.

ps. If I try use `npm install` in the project directory, it will have some error.

[image]

I have try to search from Net, most of their launching method are the same as above and does not work for me, so wanna ask that:

1. Is my method of launching React-Native is wrong in the very beginning?
2. Is there anything I need to install so that I can open old version React Native Project?
3. How can I open this project with my current situation? https://github.com/parkerdan/SampleNavigation

Thank you.

Extra Info (React Native CLI and Node Version):

```
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory

> process.version
'v8.9.4' (Node Version)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After whole day of Searching, I have found the Solution.

Whenever open any Project from Github or any sources, we have to ensure that the we have install all the required Dependencies, as Most of the Project using different type of dependencies that you may have not ever install.

**Solution:**

1. Download project

   `git clone https://github.com/parkerdan/SampleNavigation.git`

**2. Go to the Project Directory and Install dependencies (IMPORTANT)**

Note: For unknown reason, `npm install` does not work

```
npm i
```

or  `yarn i`

3. Run Project (or any launch method that work you)

   `react-native run-android`

Comment: I wonder what is the diff between yours and mine? anyway, nice to have a problem solve :D. Good luck with react-native

Comment: seem like npm install does not work for some reason @.@ it will pop out error in my question above, however npm i work well without pop out any error. I not really sure what the problem though. ps. just realised npm install and npm i are the same thing.

Comment: @IamaStudent please use yarn install and let me know if you're still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

After you clone your project from git and cd to project folder, make sure you run `npm install` before you can `react-native run-android`.

Comment: use the npm install in the Project Directory? I have tried npm install in the downloaded project directory and it will always prompt error, maybe I will include the error in my question, i edit it now.

Comment: could you provide some info about your node version & react-native-cli version?

Comment: Updated, and what  do you mean by 'Clone Your Project from Git'?

Comment: `clone` is the term for getting project from git to your machine. With the github link you gave above, here is its cloning: `git clone https://github.com/parkerdan/SampleNavigation.git`